# Include rows even if count is zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm listing out how many cases each person has in a table. I would like to include everyone that has a case at all (there is no separate user-table), even if they have no cases this week.

My current results:

```
PERSON  CASES
Jerry   1
Tom     1
```

What I'm seeking:

```
PERSON  CASES
Jerry   1
Tom     1
Spike   0
```

The query I'm running now:

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME = GETDATE()

SELECT PERSON, COUNT(CASES)
FROM TASKS
WHERE CASEDATE > CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @now)-1), @now))
GROUP BY PERSON
ORDER BY PERSON
```

As you see, my where-clause removes everyone that has no cases this week, so I'm not sure how to still include them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to have every `PERSON` available in your `TASKS` table with cases count in last week?

Comment: Move the `CASEDATE` condition from `WHERE` into the `COUNT` (using `CASE` expression.)

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas That is correct. I want everyone in `PERSON` to be shown, with whatever number of `CASES` they have last week.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this would be to put the conditional logic inside a `CASE`, inside the aggregate:

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME = GETDATE()

SELECT PERSON, SUM(CASE
            WHEN CASEDATE > CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @now)-1), @now))
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM TASKS
GROUP BY PERSON
ORDER BY PERSON
```

Comment: Perfect! I'm surprised how clean it actually turned out. EDIT: `SUM` turned out to be correct. Sorry the misunderstanding :)

Comment: @Phil - because I turned it into adding either `1` when the condition matches or `0` when it doesn't, `SUM()` seems to count the number of rows where the condition matches. Whereas `COUNT()` would see both `1` and `0` as non-null values and so count them, effectively undoing the work of putting the `CASE` there in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

I would join the TASK table to the PERSON table and use a different syntax to find the sunday:

```
SELECT 
  p.PERSON, 
  COUNT(t.CASES) cnt
FROM PERSON p
LEFT JOIN TASK t
ON p.id = t.PERSON_FK
WHERE t.CASEDATE > DATEADD(d, -1, DATEDIFF(d, -1, @now) / 7 * 7)
GROUP BY p.PERSON
ORDER BY p.PERSON
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative for finding the first day of the week, but as I stated in the original post `PERSON` is not in it's own table. Both `PERSON` and `CASES` is columns in a single table `TASKS`.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood this: *I want everyone in PERSON to be shown* Thought that meant PERSON was a table, maybe a PERSON table would be appropriate